# music21: displaying lyrics on rests

Tags: python, music21, musicxml

I want to write lyrics on music21 on both notes and rests (to show different metrical levels). I need both objects having a similar layout, but notes' lyrics position is different that rests'.

Even more, some environments like lilypond don't even support lyrics on rests. I'm ok with that but I need some way to get a nice display for those lyrics.

As a reference, I'm trying to make an example like this one in [the user guide](https://web.mit.edu/music21/doc/usersGuide/usersGuide_55_advancedMeter.html#using-beat-depth-to-provide-metrical-analysis)
[image: Example from chapter 55 of user's guide]

But if we look at the rest on measure 5, the lyric is displayed a little lower than the others. That's what I'm trying to fix.

Comment: What do the asterisks represent?

Comment: They represent the note/rest's metrical strength. For our purpose, it doesn't really matter, the issue is that lyrics are displayied differently if it's a note or a rest.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TextBox](http://web.mit.edu/music21/doc/moduleReference/moduleText.html) to display lyrics in locations that you can't otherwise put them.